# If Statement in Shiny based on values in reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am building an authentication part in my app by comparing the code sent in email and the code users submit. I have tried adding if-statement by using either in reactive(),isolate(), renderTable(). I either get the value should be in the reactive part error, or the app does not respond at all. 
Below is what I have in **Server.R**, the app does not respond at all with no error.

```
            shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {      
              myData <- reactive({
                req(input$Id)
                #connect to the database, get the data, res
                #send an email with random number, rnd
                list(res,rnd)
              })

              output$tbTable <- renderTable({req(input$Auth)
                  if (input$AuthCode==myData()$rnd) {
                myData()$res
              }
              else{
                as.data.frame(c("Authentication Failed"))
              }
              })
              output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
                filename = function() {
                  paste(input$Id, " filname.xlsx", sep = "")
                },
                content = function(file) {
                  write.csv(myData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
                }
              )#this part need to depend on the if-statement as well
            }
            )
```

**UI.R**

```
                ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(title = "aaa",
                titlePanel("aaa"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(

                    textInput("Id", "Enter Acct Name below"),
                    submitButton(text="Submit"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    numericInput("AuthCode",label="Authentication",value=""),
                    actionButton("Auth",label="Submit"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    tags$hr(),
                    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
                    )) 
                ),
            )
            )
```

Comment: why have you used this expression `as.data.frame(c("Authentication Failed"))` ?

Comment: I am not quite clear about the data structure in Shiny. As res, the output is a dataframe, so I converted this string to dataframe to avoid mismatch. Appreciate if any input on the adverse affect if it is the problem.

Comment: Are you okay if there is a modal box saying authentication failed?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: And why do you have the first submit button, can't it be one button for both account and authentication code?

Comment: The email is supposed to be sent to a changeable email address based on input$Id, like the account owner, for authentication. So after the submit triggers the email, the correct recipient will enter the code in the email for authentication. So I guess there has to be 2 buttons.

Comment: Cool. You had used `submit` there which is another issue. got it!

Comment: I read post about actionButton is preferred, but submitButton works well in older version without adding the authentication part. Really appreciate if you can help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got the fixed to do what you want. Please check. I've done the following changes

- Replaced your `submitButton` to `actionButton` as `Acc` and using `observeEvent` to call that.
- The authentication is also now triggered by an `observeEvent` when the second button is clicked
- Excel extension wouldn't work in `write.csv` so changed the extension.

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {      


# the first button will trigger this  


  observeEvent(input$Acc,{
  #  myData <- reactive({
      req(input$Id)
      #connect to the database, get the data, res
      #send an email with random number, rnd
      #list(res,rnd)
     myData <<- list(res = 123,rnd = 345) #passing test value and storing it as global variable for accessing in other functions
   # })

    cat("mydata done")

  })


  # the second button will trigger this
  observeEvent(input$Auth,{

    output$tbTable <- renderTable({
      #req(input$Auth)
      if (input$AuthCode==myData$rnd) {
        myData$res
      }
      else{
        #as.data.frame(c("Authentication Failed"))
        shiny::showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Important message",
          "Authentication Failed!"
        ))
      }
    })
  })


  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$Id, " filname.csv", sep = "") #renamed it to csv because write.csv writes to csv not excel
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(myData, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )#this part need to depend on the if-statement as well
}
)
```

#### ui.R

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(title = "aaa",
                        titlePanel("aaa"),
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(

                            textInput("Id", "Enter Acct Name below"),
                            actionButton("Acc",label="Click to send code"),
                            tags$hr(),
                            numericInput("AuthCode",label="Authentication",value=000),
                            actionButton("Auth",label="Submit"),
                            tags$hr(),
                            tags$hr(),
                            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data")
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            tabsetPanel(
                              tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("tbTable"))
                            )) 
                        )
)
)
```